# Add custom plugin mention to tinyMCE in joomla 2.5

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, tinymce

I want to extend tinyMCE to add a custom plugin mention.
Its very straight forward to add it on standalone page. But I'm struggling to add the same into joomla site for the tinyMCE.

This is the link, to which I'm referring.
    https://github.com/CogniStreamer/tinyMCE-mention

- mention plugin is added to the plugins folder for tinyMCE.

So where and how do I add the source code for mention to tinyMCE?

Hoping for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Either install your created plugin using extension manager or add your plugin in plugins->editors-xtd. Also don't forget to enable the plugin.